# How to break for loop in Acceleo template

Tags: acceleo

Can someone help me with loop of for in Acceleo template mtl.

```
[for (it:attributeClass|amodelClass.classHasAttribute)]
[for (it2:attributeClass|amodelClass.classHasAttribute)]
    [if (it.attributeName.endsWith(it2.attributeName))]
    [else]
    if ((![it.attributeName/].equals([it2.attributeName/]))&&  ([it.attributeName/] > [it2.attributeName/])){
        throw new RuleException(ProjectCatalog.PROJECT_MSG_SET,  ProjectCatalog.DATE_FINAL_BEFORE_DATE_INITIAL);
    }
    [/if]           
[/for][/for]
```

I need that the for loop happen once only. Can someone help me?

Comment: Can you be more specific? Which for loop do you want to break? What do  you have as input and what do you want exactly? A little scenario would be great :)

Comment: I want to break the first for loop:

[for (it: attributeClass | amodelClass.classHasAttribute)]

The setting is two records and each record possesses a structure with initial_date values and estimate_end_date

will be that became more clear my doubts?

Comment: I think I get it, you only want to get the first element of the `classHasAttribute` collection and perform the `for` on the remaining collection without the first element? (assuming you have a collection `{a, b, c}`, you want to have `it` matched with `a` and `it2` iterate on `{b, c}`. Is that it?

Comment: i have a collection {a,b} and i want it matched with {a} and it2 iterate on {a,b}, because in my code i only print when it equal it2, thus i will have it.a equals it2.a. I only will print once. Nowadays my result is: it.a equals it2.a and it.b equals it2.b. I have duplicated values.

Comment: If I understand well, you can try to change the first `for` to a `let`, the `for` will become: `[let it : attributeClass = amodelClass.classHasAttribute->asSequence()->at(1)]`. This fragment will only take the first element of your collection for `it` and `it2` will iterate on the same collection. If that's what you want, I will turn this message into a post and add more details ;)

Comment: Hi Vicent Aranega,

Thank you very much for the tips

Regards,
Fabio.